# Diferença entre funções de alta-ordem e primeira-classe

Tags: javascript, programação-funcional

Em linguagem funcional, qual a diferença entre **funções de alta-ordem** (*high-order functions*) e **funções primeira-classe** (*first-class functins*)?

Em JavaScript, qual seria a diferença entre esses dois tipos de funções?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Uma linguagem tem **funções de primeira classe**, quando funções podem ser
tratadas como valores que podem ser passados, manipulados, retornados...
ou seja, é possível operar funções. Este conceito é um atributo da linguagem,
ou ela tem ou não tem.

**Função de alta ordem** é uma função que recebe ou retorna uma função.
<s>Só é possível definir uma função de alta ordem, se a linguagem tem
**funções de primeira classe**</s>, pois é necessário que funções sejam *"passáveis"*.
Este conceito é um atributo da função, ou ela é ou não é.

**EDIT**

Linguagens que não possuem funções de primeira classe, como o C, ainda assim
permitem a criação de funções de alta ordem, usando ponteiros de função.

Javascript é uma linguagem que possui funções de primeira classe, ou seja,
é possível passar, retornar e operar funções.

**Referência:**

- [Higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)<sup>(inglês)</sup>
- [First-class function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)<sup>(inglês)</sup>

Comment: O Java 8 possui algo parecido com Funções de alta ordem, que permite [referenciar funções](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).