# O conceito de High Order Functions em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou lendo **Eloquent Javascript** para ter uma base de javascript. Eu estava entendendo bem, já que o fundamental não muda em relação a outras linguagens, como tipos de dados (int, string, bool, objects, arrays). Porém cheguei na parte de **Abstração**. Sei que isto também faz parte das outras linguagens, sendo uma das bases para muitos *design patterns* por ai,

**porém eu não entendi o conceito de High Order Functions**.

Vamos ao exemplo mostrado em Eloquent Javascript p. 90:

> Functions that operate on other functions, either by taking them as
>   arguments or by returning them, are called higher-order functions.
>
> (Funções que operam sobre outras funções, seja tomando-as como argumentos ou retornando-as, são chamadas de funções de alta-ordem).

```
function greaterThan ( n ) {

  return function ( m ) { return m > n; };

}

var greaterThan10 = greaterThan (10) ;
console . log ( greaterThan10 (11) ) ;

// → true
```

O que eu não entendi, principalmente, foi este exemplo ai. Principalmente a parte dos argumentos.

Primeiro ele define `greaterThan10 = greaterThan10(10)`, e passa o argumento 10 para esta *function*, **e dai ele pode chamar a VARIAVEL como *function*?** E os argumentos? O primeiro argumento passado na definição vai continuar lá? (10)

Estou um pouco confuso, eu gostaria de uma explicação um pouco mais simples, ou um exemplo em que este conceito fosse mais visível.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Diferença entre funções de alta-ordem e primeira-classe](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11403/91) e 
[Qual a diferença entre as funções var name = function e function name?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/91)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Esse conceito é muito comum em programação funcional, onde o conceito é evitar o `state` e usar funções, encadeamento de funções para fazer o que é preciso fazer pelo programa. Funções que aceitem outras funções como argumentos são chamadas `high-order functions`.

De modo genérico funções como `.map()` e `.filter()` são funções que caem nesta categoria, pois consomem funções como argumento.

Explicando o teu exemplo:

```
function greaterThan(n) {
    return function(m) {
        return m > n;
    };
}
```

Aqui tens uma função que devolve uma função. Isto é importante. A função não muda um estado de uma variável, é simplesmente uma ferramenta para ser encadeada ou seja uma função de ordem superior, ou seja uma ferramenta para criar outras funções. Daí ser chamado "abstração" pois pode ser usado em *N* contextos diferentes.

Podes então gerar uma outra função, mais específica, fazendo

```
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
```

que na prática é o mesmo que:

```
var greaterThan10 = function(m) {
    return m > 10;
};
```

Esta função `greaterThan10` irá retornar um valor booleano. Neste caso a função recebe um numero e retorna um booleano.

Comment: Era isto que eu não estava visualizando, a parte do `var greaterThan10 = function(m) {
    return m > 10;
};` Obrigado por me ajudar a entender.

Answer (score 2):

Sei que já fazem anos, mas vou deixar uma contribuição nessa pergunta para pessoas do futuro que caiam nela...

Além do que foi colocado pelo Sérgio na resposta aceita, vale mencionar o conceito de closure, que é fundamental na maioria das implementações de funções de alta-ordem.

O closure é a capacidade de uma função de ler escopos que são maiores que ela. Por exemplo, acessar o estado global.

Isso na programação funcional é problemático, pois torna a função impura. No entanto, se uma função de alta ordem for usada para criar um escopo controlado (imutável) retornando uma função que faz uso dele, não temos esse problema.

Veja o exemplo da pergunta (vou só atualizar a sintaxe para ES6):

```js
const greaterThan = n => m => m > n;
```

Primeiro recebemos n, que fica armazenado. Por closure a função `m => m > n` tem acesso a esse n, que não tem como ser modificado.

Sendo assim, quando invocamos greaterThan(10) retornamos na verdade `m => m > 10`. Afinal n é imutável.

Se n é imutável a função continua pura (sempre retorna o mesmo valor para os mesmos parâmetros e não produz efeitos colaterais).

A combinação de alta-ordem com closure é uma grande ferramenta para especializar funções genéricas:

```js
const replaceAll = (from, to, text) => text.split(from).joint(to);
```

Na função acima, temos que passar todos os parâmetros de uma vez se quisermos fazer um replaceAll, por exemplo:

```js
replaceAll("{{nome}}", "Jones", "Hello {{nome}}!"); //Hello Jones
```

Se usarmos closure e alta-ordem, é possível usar uma técnica equivalente a aplicação parcial (passar menos parâmetros do que a função precisa):

```js
const replaceAll = (from, to) => text => text.split(from).join(to);
```

Agora podemos especializá-la:

```js
const replaceDotForComma = replaceAll(".", ",");
const replaceDoubleQuoteForSingleQuote = replaceAll("\"", "'");
const replaceWindowsLineBreakForLinux = replaceAll("\r\n", "\n");
```

Para usar qualquer uma dessas funções, basta passar o texto:

```js
replaceDotForComma("10.5"); // 10,5
replaceDoubleQuoteForSingleQuote('"hello"'); // 'hello'
replaceWindowsLineBreakForLinux("teste/r/n"); // "teste\n"
```

Não ter que passar esses parâmetros todas as vezes é bastante útil para evitar erros e inconsistências entre os replaces feitos no programa...

Comment: Ótima resposta, parabéns! :)