# O que são Renderless Components?

Tags: javascript, react, vue.js, componentes

Qual exatamente é a utilidade de um componente Renderless? Existe alguma vantagem real no seu uso?

Comment: Vale a pena ver: https://adamwathan.me/renderless-components-in-vuejs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um componente *Renderless* é um componente que não gera HTML próprio, ele existe somente para estruturar outros componentes e/ou tratar dados que são passados ao interior dele. Um componente *Renderless* é um caso específico de [*High order component*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150499/129).

Imagina um cenário onde queres mostrar números pares ou números ímpares. A funcionalidade de filtrar números pares ou ímpares pode ser extraída e colocada à parte. Assim passando um template diferente o componente *renderless* encarrega-se de tratar os dados mantêm-se fora do HTML.

Exemplo com um componente `<lista>`:

```js
Vue.component('lista', {
  props: ['numbers', 'even'],
  computed: {
    filteredNumbers() {
      return (this.numbers || [])
        .filter(nr => this.even === (nr % 2 === 0));
    }
  },
  render() {
    return this.$scopedSlots.default({
      numbers: this.filteredNumbers
    });
  }
});

new Vue({
  name: 'App',
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Pares</p>
  <lista :numbers="numbers" :even="true">
    <ul slot-scope="{numbers}">
      <li v-for="nr in numbers">{{nr}}</li>
    </ul>
  </lista>
  <p>Ímpares</p>
  <lista :numbers="numbers" :even="false">
    <div slot-scope="{numbers}">
      <span>{{numbers.join(', ')}}</span>
    </div>
  </lista>
</div>
```

Dois artigos em Inglês com exemplos mais detalhados:

- https://adamwathan.me/renderless-components-in-vuejs/
- https://css-tricks.com/building-renderless-vue-components/

Comment: React Or Vuejs? :)

Comment: @Marconi é indiferente, o conceito é o mesmo mas em cada tecnologia é feito de maneira ligeiramente diferente. Dei um exemplo com Vue mas podia ser com React.

Comment: Sergio eu fiz foi uma brincadeira de qual dos dois prefere... :)

Comment: @Marconi prefiro Vue :) Ambas as bibliotecas são boas.