# Qual o equivalente Java desta lambda em Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, expressões-lambda, java-8, ioc

Em seu texto sobre [Inversão de Controle](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html), Fowler usa como exemplo um trecho de código em Ruby que promove o dito princípio ao *"invocar um método bind sobre o campo de entrada de texto que passa um nome de evento e uma Lambda como argumento. Sempre que a caixa de entrada de texto detecta o evento, ela chama o código na clausura. Usar clausuras assim é muito conveniente, porém muitas linguagens não as suportam"*.

```
require 'tk'
root = TkRoot.new()
name_label = TkLabel.new() {text "What is Your Name?"}
name_label.pack
name = TkEntry.new(root).pack
name.bind("FocusOut") {process_name(name)}
quest_label = TkLabel.new() {text "What is Your Quest?"}
quest_label.pack
quest = TkEntry.new(root).pack
quest.bind("FocusOut") {process_quest(quest)}
Tk.mainloop()
```

Acredito que ele se refere por exemplo à seguinte linha:

```
name.bind("FocusOut") {process_name(name)}
```

Não conheço Ruby. Gostaria de saber se a introdução de lambdas no Java 8 permitiu fazer algo semelhante e como funcionaria no caso dele. Gostaria se possível que a explicação ilustrasse por que não era possível fazer isso nas versões anteriores do Java, para melhor compreensão do problema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Closures

O seguinte não é lambda, mas sim um bloco ou *closure*. É bem comum ver blocos em [funções de alta ordem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) atuando como [funções de primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11403/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-alta-ordem-e-primeira-classe), não só em Ruby mas como na maioria das linguagens. Um exemplo em Ruby:

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |item| item + 1 }
# => [2, 3, 4]
```

No exemplo, `Array#map` é uma função de alta ordem, e a função/bloco, passada como parâmetro, atua como função de primeira classe.

Outro em JavaScript:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function(item) {
    return item + 1;
});
// => [2, 3, 4]
```

De forma simples, uma *closure* é uma função que pode ser guardada em uma variável e pode acessar outras variáveis locais ao escopo dela.

Se não fossem as closures, [o JavaScript não funcionaria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1).

- [Ruby Blocks](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html)
- [What Is the Difference Between a Block, a Proc, and a Lambda in Ruby?](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/)
- [Como funcionam closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1859/como-funcionam-closures-em-javascript)

## Closures vs Lambdas

Essa é uma longa discussão de difere e implementação para implementação. Uma função lambda é uma função anônima, sem nome. Em muitas linguagens, internamente um *lambda* é convertido em uma declaração normal de função.

As closures tem uma grande diferença para funções *lambdas* pois as closures se envelopam ao seu contexto, dando assim acesso às variáveis de seu [escopo léxico](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/lexical-scoping-static-scoping). E é por isso que as *closures* são chamadas também de *lexical closures*.

- [What is the difference between a 'closure' and a 'lambda'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda)
- [Martin Fowler: Lambda](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Lambda.html)

## Java

Anteriormente comentei que closures e lambdas eram de uma forma no papel, mas variam de implementação para implementação, então... no Java existem *closures*, mas essas são idênticas às funções *lambdas*.

> A closure is a lambda expression paired with an environment that binds
>   each of its free variables to a value. In Java, lambda expressions
>   will be implemented by means of closures, so the two terms have come
>   to be used interchangeably in the community. [Fonte.](http://www.lambdafaq.org/lambdas-and-closures-whats-the-difference/)

Isso quer dizer que no Java as expressões *lambda* são encapsuladas no escopo local, assim como as *closures*, conceitualmente.

Desde o Java 8, existem [expressões lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Veja:

```
StateOwner stateOwner = new StateOwner();

stateOwner.addStateListener(
    (oldState, newState) -> System.out.println("State changed")
);
```

Este é o lambda (que também atua como closure) no Java.

```
(oldState, newState) -> System.out.println("State changed")
```

- [Are Java 8 Lambdas Closures?](http://bruceeckel.github.io/2015/10/17/are-java-8-lambdas-closures/)
- [What is closure in Java?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-closure-in-Java)

## Versões anteriores do Java

As versões anteriores do Java permitiam fazer isso, mas de um jeito um pouco diferente e que não é lambda, pois não eram funções anônimas.

```
StateOwner stateOwner = new StateOwner();

stateOwner.addStateListener(new StateChangeListener() {

    public void onStateChange(State oldState, State newState) {
        System.out.println("State changed")
    }
});
```

Veja que a função `onStateChange` tem um nome e não é lambda. Mas era possível passar uma função como parâmetro de outra.

Outro obstáculo era que no Java 7 ou inferior, para passar uma função como parâmetro de outra, a assinatura do método que recebe deveria ser uma interface, assim respeitando os tipos. No Java 8 você pode usar o `Function<TipoRetorno>`.

- [Closures in Java 7](https://javabeat.net/closures-in-java-7-0/)
- [Closures For Java (Neal Gafter)](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/08/closures-for-java.html)