# Por que devemos usar method references ao invés de lambdas?

Tags: java

Ao passarmos funções como argumento para [funções de alta-ordem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11428/100), geralmente podemos usar dois mecanismos distintos do Java 8+:

#### 1. Lambdas:

```
var averageLength = stringList.stream()
    .filter(s -> s != null)
    .mapToInt(s -> s.length())
    .average();
```

#### 2. Method references:

```
var averageLength = stringList.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .mapToInt(String::length)
    .average();
```

Por padrão o IntelliJ IDEA recomenda a substituição de *lambdas* por *method references* (mesmo quando o código se torna ligeiramente mais extenso como no caso do exemplo acima).

Minha pergunta é, por que é recomendável usar *method references* ao invés de *lambdas*?
É uma questão puramente de legibilidade? Reaproveitamento? *Performance*?

Comment: Se você que é você não sabe, quero ver quem vai saber :D mas se está perguntando algo assim é porque deve estar engatilhando uma resposta para a própria pergunta. Permita-me me adiantar e linkar uma resposta de um cara que com certeza sabe o porquê (Brian Goetz): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493905/2241463

Comment: Hoje mesmo dei preferência a uma classe anônima `Runnable` por questão de legibilidade, com método `run()` e tudo. Queria isolar uma funcionalidade dela num método que ela mesma chamasse, e se usasse uma lambda (o que via de regra é mais legível) isso não seria permitido. Não lembro o caso agora, então não vou descartar um possível mau design da minha parte. :)

Comment: Mas só para ver como essa coisa de qual tem a maior legibilidade não dá pra levar a ferro e fogo, depende de cada pessoa.

Comment: Dá para encaixar classes anônimas, *ETA expansion* (ou seja lá qual o nome dado a isso no mundo Java), `LambdaMetafactory`, etc na pergunta. Só não mencionei para não complicar ainda mais :).

Comment: _"essa coisa de qual tem a maior legibilidade não dá pra levar a ferro e fogo"._ Vi agora que me expressei mal aqui, legibilidade naturalmente é muito importante, o que pretendia dizer é que a questão de qual é a forma mais legível é relativa e depende de percepção pessoal.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, só pro curiosidade https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/10/java-8-and-method-references-in-intellij-idea-12/

Answer (score -3):

Method references são uma maneira concisa de criar expressões lambda que se referem a um método existente. Elas permitem que você crie expressões lambda que são mais legíveis e concisas do que as lambdas tradicionais. Além disso, elas podem ser mais fáceis de depurar e manter do que as lambdas tradicionais.

Por essas razões, é recomendável usar method references ao invés de lambdas quando for possível fazê-lo sem sacrificar a legibilidade do código. Isso pode ajudar a tornar o código mais conciso e fácil de entender.