# Como entender o mapeamento (map) de lista de funções em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, map

```
lista = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

def square(y):
    return (y**2)
    
def cube(y):
    return (y**3)

funcs = [square, cube]

for i in lista:
    valor = map(lambda x: x(i), funcs)
    print(list((valor)))
```

Saída:

```
[0, 0]
[1, 1]
[4, 8]
[9, 27]
[16, 64]
```

Não consigo entender, a função `map` está recebendo uma lista de funções no seu segundo argumento.

Até agora só havia visto lista de valores nesse argumento. E na função lambda, o `x(i)` está passando cada elemento da lista como argumento para cada função na lista `funcs` (que tem cada elemento uma função definida).

Esse exemplo está muito diferente do havia aprendido sobre a função `map`.

Alguém pode explicar como interpretar esse código?

Answer (score 7):

> Até agora só havia visto lista de valores nesse argumento.

Não tem diferença porque, de certo modo, uma lista de funções não deixa de ser uma lista de valores. A lógica é a mesma, vamos recapitular.

O propósito mais genérico do `map` é fazer um *mapeamento* sobre um contêiner. No Python, a função *built-in* `map` mapeia cada elemento de um iterável (o contêiner) a uma função fornecida. Esse iterável pode ser um lista, tupla, etc.

Isso significa que, para *cada* um dos valores do iterável (uma lista, por exemplo) fornecido no segundo argumento, a função de mapeamento será aplicada, gerando uma nova lista de mesmo comprimento, mas com os valores alterados de acordo com a função de mapeamento.

Com essa definição, voltemos ao código da pergunta:

```
lista = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

def square(y):
        return (y**2)
    
def cube(y):
        return (y**3)

funcs = [square, cube]

for i in lista:
    valor = map(lambda x: x(i), funcs)
    print(list(valor))
```

Como o `map` está dentro de um `for`, ele será executado várias vezes. Nesse caso específico, executar-se-á `map` para cada um dos elementos da lista `lista`.

Para analisar o `map`, podemos estudar o caso de somente uma das iterações. Vejamos o que ocorre na terceira iteração (onde o valor de `i` é `2`):

```
# `i` está definido como `2`.
valor = map(lambda x: x(i), funcs)
print(list(valor))
```

Forneceremos ao `map` o iterável `funcs`, que é basicamente uma lista de funções. Para cada uma das funções dessa lista, executaremos a função de mapeamento passada.

No caso, essa função de mapeamento é, basicamente, aplicar a função do mapeamento atual ao valor `i`.

Então, `i` sendo 2 (terceira iteração), o `map` produzirá um iterável correspondente a:

```
[square(2), cube(2)]
# Que é avaliado para: [4, 8]
```

Talvez a dificuldade de entender o `map` tenha advindo do fato de um mapeamento ser feito a cada uma das iterações do `for` externo. Nesse caso, ao analisar somente uma das iterações podemos ter uma noção melhor do que, de fato, o `map` está fazendo.

Com esse entendimento, podemos expandir para um nível superior do código: o mapeamento das funções de `funcs` será feito para cada um dos elementos de `lista`.

---

Outra coisa que pode ajudar a entender é fazer um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/220526/69296), mas aí acho que já foge do escopo desta resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos começar do começo. Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> *Functions are first-class objects.*

Ou seja, em Python as funções são "[cidadãos de primeira classe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)": elas são tratadas como se fossem valores "normais", podendo ser colocadas em listas, atribuídas a uma variável, passadas como parâmetro para outras funções, etc. Sobre este assunto, você pode ler mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109109/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11403/112052).

---

Portanto, uma função pode ser atribuída a uma variável:

```py
def square(y):
        return y ** 2
    
def cube(y):
        return y ** 3

# atribui a função a uma variável
funcao = square
# como "funcao" aponta para "square", posso chamá-la normalmente
print(funcao(3)) # 9

# atribui outra função na mesma variável
funcao = cube
# agora "funcao" aponta para "cube"
print(funcao(3)) # 27
```

E também posso criar uma lista contendo várias funções, percorrer essa lista em um *loop* e chamar todas elas:

```py
def square(y):
        return y ** 2
    
def cube(y):
        return y ** 3

# lista contendo as funções
funcs = [square, cube]
# para cada função da lista, chamá-la passando o número 3 como argumento
for funcao in funcs:
    print(f'chamando {funcao.__name__}: {funcao(3)}')
```

A saída deste código é:

```
chamando square: 9
chamando cube: 27
```

---

Agora sobre o `map`: tudo que ele faz é aplicar uma função a todos os elementos de um iterável. Ou seja, se eu faço:

```py
def dobro(n):
    return n * 2

valores = [1, 2, 3]
for result in map(dobro, valores):
    print(result)
```

Isso irá imprimir `2`, `4` e `6`, pois `map(dobro, valores)` aplica a função `dobro` a cada um dos elementos da lista `valores`. Essencialmente, isso seria equivalente a:

```py
for valor in valores:
    print(dobro(valor))
```

---

Só que no seu caso a lista não tem valores que são passados para uma função. O que ela tem são funções que serão chamadas com determinado valor. Ou seja, seria como fazer isso:

```py
# para cada função da lista "funcs", chamá-la passando o "3" como argumento
for funcao in funcs:
    print(funcao(3))
```

E nesse caso, o equivalente usando `map` teria que ser:

```py
for result in map(lambda funcao: funcao(3), funcs):
    print(result)
```

Ou seja, a função que `map` recebe é um `lambda` (que [no fundo também é uma função](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)), que recebe como argumento uma função e a chama (passando, no caso, o número `3` como argumento). Ou seja, em vez de eu mesmo chamar a função diretamente dentro do *loop*, é o `map` que a chama e retorna o resultado (por isso, dentro do `for` eu já posso pegar o resultado direto).

---

Mas no seu caso você não está iterando pelo `map`, e sim pegando o resultado dele e passando para `list`, que por sua vez cria uma lista contendo todos os resultados. Ou seja, quando você faz:

```py
valor = map(lambda funcao: funcao(3), funcs)
print(list(valor)) # [9, 27]
```

Seria equivalente a fazer:

```py
results = [] # cria uma lista vazia
# para cada resultado do map, adicioná-lo na lista
for result in map(lambda funcao: funcao(3), funcs):
    results.append(result)
print(results) # [9, 27]
```

E por fim, no seu código tudo isso é feito dentro de um *loop*, que itera pelos valores da lista `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. Nos exemplos acima eu sempre passei o número `3` para as funções, mas no seu *loop* ele faz isso para todos os valores da lista.

Ou seja, primeiro ele chama as funções para o `0` e imprime a lista com os resultados, depois faz o mesmo para o `1`, para o `2` etc.

---

E só para constar, outra forma de criar esta lista com os resultados seria usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
for i in lista:
    print([ funcao(i) for funcao in funcs ])
```